# Cannot find easyrsa executable

Tags: openvpn

I am following [Digital Ocean's Guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-and-configure-an-openvpn-server-on-ubuntu-20-04) for setting up an OpenVPN instance.

I have installed `openvpn` and `easyrsa` on my server. However, when the guide says to run `./easyrsa init-pki` there's a problem: `easyrsa` doesn't exist.

It is not available under /usr/share/easy-rsa:

```
ll /usr/share/easy-rsa/
total 120
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Aug 23 16:08 ./
drwxr-xr-x 131 root root  4096 Aug 23 16:05 ../
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root   119 Nov  9  2013 build-ca*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root   352 Nov  9  2013 build-dh*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root   188 Nov  9  2013 build-inter*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root   163 Nov  9  2013 build-key*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root   157 Nov  9  2013 build-key-pass*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root   249 Nov  9  2013 build-key-pkcs12*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root   268 Nov  9  2013 build-key-server*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root   213 Nov  9  2013 build-req*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root   158 Nov  9  2013 build-req-pass*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root   449 Nov  9  2013 clean-all*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  1471 Nov  9  2013 inherit-inter*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root   302 Nov  9  2013 list-crl*
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  7859 Jul 13  2015 openssl-0.9.6.cnf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  8416 Jul 13  2015 openssl-0.9.8.cnf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  8313 Jul 13  2015 openssl-1.0.0.cnf
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 13192 Jul 13  2015 pkitool*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  1035 Jul 13  2015 revoke-full*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root   178 Nov  9  2013 sign-req*
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  2119 Aug 23 16:08 vars
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root   740 Nov  9  2013 whichopensslcnf*
```

How do I get the `easyrsa` executable?

Ubuntu Server 22.04

Comment: Which distro and version of Linux are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu Server 22.04

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you've somehow managed to install an ancient version of the software. I tried to reproduce your results on Ubuntu 22.04 with `apt install openvpn easy-rsa -y`. That gave me OpenVPN 2.5.5 and Easy RSA 3.0.8. The dates  are in 2020 and 2021, not 2013 and 2015.